# Python override __getattr__ for nested assignment, but not for referencing?

Tags: python

Here's the behavior I'm looking for:

```
>>> o = SomeClass()
>>> # Works: 
>>> o.foo.bar = 'bar' 
>>> print o.foo.bar
'bar'
>>> # The in-between object would be of type SomeClass as well:
>>> print o.foo 
>>> <__main__.SomeClass object at 0x7fea2f0ef810>

>>> # I want referencing an unassigned attribute to fail: 
>>> print o.baz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
    print o.baz
AttributeError: 'SomeClass' object has no attribute 'baz'
```

In other words, I want to override `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` (and possibly `__getattribute__`) in such a way that work similarly to defaultdict, allowing assignment to arbitrary attributes, but if an attribute is just referenced but not assigned to, that it throws an AttributeError as it normally would.

Is this possible?

Comment: Huh? Python-the-language already lets you do that...

Comment: Yeah, I think I've over-simplified my problem statement.  I'm actually working on something more complex.  Let me rephrase it.

Comment: This question turns up once a month: You want a object that behaves differently *now* (`raise` or work) depending on what a *later* call to it (get something or not) will be. Python can do many things, but looking into the future is not one of them. While you certainly can emulate this to a certain point, I think the whole idea is just very wrong. A trivial workaround would be to use `o['foo.baz']` instead, which simply works.

Comment: Yeah, I can see this turning into one ugly hack. >_<

Comment: I think this is actually just a simple case of deferred assignment / deferred evaluation.  It's not looking into the future, per say.   I'll answer this question with my own code snippet when I'm done, for you to comment on.  I can't use the o['foo.baz'] syntax because I'm actually initializing this thing from a big nested dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've got so far:

```
def raise_wrapper(wrapped_method=None):
    def method(tmp_instance, *args, **kawrgs):
        raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (
                type(tmp_instance._parent).__name__, tmp_instance._key))
    if wrapped_method:
        method.__doc__ = wrapped_method.__doc__
    return method


class TemporaryValue(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, key):
        self._parent = parent
        self._key = key

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in ('_parent', '_key'):
            return object.__setattr__(self, key, value)

        newval = ObjectLike()
        object.__setattr__(self._parent, self._key, newval)
        return object.__setattr__(newval, key, value)

    __eq__ = raise_wrapper(object.__eq__)
    # __del__ = raise_wrapper()
    # __repr__ = raise_wrapper(object.__repr__)
    __str__ = raise_wrapper(object.__str__)
    __lt__ = raise_wrapper(object.__lt__)
    __le__ = raise_wrapper(object.__le__)
    __eq__ = raise_wrapper(object.__eq__)
    __ne__ = raise_wrapper(object.__ne__)
    __cmp__ = raise_wrapper()
    __hash__ = raise_wrapper(object.__hash__)
    __nonzero__ = raise_wrapper()
    __unicode__ = raise_wrapper()
    __delattr__ = raise_wrapper(object.__delattr__)
    __call__ = raise_wrapper(object.__call__)


class ObjectLike(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        newtmp = TemporaryValue(self, key)
        object.__setattr__(self, key, newtmp)
        return newtmp

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)


o = ObjectLike()
o.foo.bar = 'baz'
print o.foo.bar
print o.not_set_yet
print o.some_function()
if o.unset > 3: 
    print "yes" 
else:
    print "no"
```

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible in Python.

What you're asking is for this:

```
>>> o = SomeClass()
>>> o.foo.bar = 'bar' 
>>> print o.foo.bar
'bar'
>>> a = o.baz
raises AttributeError
```

This can't be done.  There's no way to distinguish

```
>>> o.foo.bar = 'bar'
```

from

```
>>> temp = o.foo
>>> temp.bar = 'bar'
```

They're logically equivalent, and under the hood Python is doing the same thing in both cases.  You can't differentiate them in order to raise an exception in the latter case but not the former.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
class AutoVivifier(object):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        value = type(self)()
        object.__setattr__(self,key,value)
        return value

o=AutoVivifier()
o.foo.bar='baz'
print(o.foo.bar)
# baz
print(o.foo.baz)
# <__main__.AutoVivifier object at 0xb776bb0c>
o.foo.baz='bing'
print(o.foo.baz)
# bing
```

This doesn't raise any AttributeErrors, but it is easy to tell when an attribute chain has no previously assigned value -- the expression will be an instance of `Autovivifier`. That is, `isinstance(o.foo.baz,AutoVivifier)` is True.

I think the implementation is cleaner this way, than if you defined all sorts of special methods like `__str__` and `__eq__` to raise AttributeErrors.

I'm still not clear on why you need to raise AttributeErrors in the first place, but perhaps using AutoVivifier you can write functions or methods that achieve your goals, with `isinstance(...,AutoVivifier)` tests replacing `try...except AttributeError` blocks.

Comment: I don't understand why the overriding is necessary for something that is a default behavior to begin with?

Comment: Here's the direction I'm working in now:  The getattr for 'foo' on o returns a TemporaryClass value.  If I ever call setattr on that temporary, then the assignment actually takes place.  Otherwise, everything else (`__str__`, etc.) on the TemporaryClass raises an AttributeError.  I think it's a promising direction but I haven't worked out the kinks yet.

Comment: @slacy: If `o.foo` returns a Temporary value, then `print(o.foo)` would not raise an AttributeError.

Comment: It would if TemporaryClass.__str__() raised the AttributeError().

Comment: As would `__eq__`, etc.   All those comparison and "output" methods would have to raise AttributeError()

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I'm coming up with, but I'd like o.foo to be of type SomeClass and be valid.  This can be accomplished by passing more details to the Temporory constructor and doing a deferred assignment in __setattr__.

Comment: This only works because you're printing `o.baz`, which happens to call `__str__`; it does not work in general.

Comment: @slacy: I worry that this setup is unobvious and fragile -- it might break in some way I haven't yet considered. Are you sure there is no simpler way to approach your overall problem?

Comment: One place this fails is under: `o.foo.bar.baz = 5; print o.foo`, although perhaps this behavior is desirable?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is essentially 'serialization' but to/from a dict to a 1st class object.  In other words, I want a class that is constructed like `m = Mapper({'a': {'b', 'c'}, 'd': 'e'})` and then can be reassigned like `m.a.b.r = 's'`.  Internally, the class needs to preserve "dicty-ness" so that I serialize the 1st class object back to a dict again.  The dicts come from mongodb, and the 1st class objects are emulating an ORM, so I'd like to preserve the semantics outlined thusfar.  (Yes, direct dict access would be easier)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean. The language features already let you do that:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     pass
...
>>> f = MyClass()
>>> f.foo = 5
>>> print f.foo
5
>>> f.baz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'baz'
>>>
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I over-simplified my problem statement.  See the re-statement above.  I'm looking for nested object assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
[~/.src/pyusb-1.0.0-a1]
|4>class SomeClass: pass
   ...: 

[~/.src/pyusb-1.0.0-a1]
|5>o = SomeClass()

[~/.src/pyusb-1.0.0-a1]
|6>o.foo='bar'

[~/.src/pyusb-1.0.0-a1]
|7>print o.foo
bar

[~/.src/pyusb-1.0.0-a1]
|8>print o.baz
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

AttributeError: SomeClass instance has no attribute 'baz'

[~/.src/pyusb-1.0.0-a1]
|9>
```

Comment: Yeah, realized that I had oversimplified my problem statement.  Please see the new question definition above.  I'm actually hoping for nested object assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is really hacky, but perhaps a start at what you want:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, "_SomeClass__children", {})
        object.__setattr__(self, "_SomeClass__empty", True)

    def __getattr__(self, k):
        if k not in self.__children:
            self.__children[k] = SomeClass()
        return self.__children[k]

    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        object.__setattr__(self, "_SomeClass__empty", False)
        object.__setattr__(self, k, v)

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.__hasvalue():
            raise AttributeError("Never truly existed")
        return object.__str__(self)

    def __hasvalue(self):
        if not self.__empty:
            return True
        return any(v.__hasvalue() for v in self.__children.itervalues())

o = SomeClass()
o.foo.bar = 'bar'
print o.foo.bar
print o.foo
print o.baz
```

And output:

```
bar
<__main__.SomeClass object at 0x7f2431404c90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spam.py", line 29, in <module>
    print o.baz
  File "spam.py", line 17, in __str__
    raise AttributeError("Never truly existed")
AttributeError: Never truly existed
```

Comment: `print o.baz` was really just an example, and I'd need this to work for `if o.baz` and `if o.baz == f.bar` and `o.baz += 2` and `bla[o.baz] = 3` etc.  It's not just print/str that needs to raise the attribute error.

Comment: @slacy, implementing the others are left as an exercise to the reader. :) you'll need __add__, __nonzero___, etc.

Comment: that is truly unsettling to look at. @slacy, you're already getting more from carl than you deserve :P